# Speed of finding content in a set vs a list in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I experimented with the speed of witch Python finds an item. I have a csv file with 1 million rows of unique date-times. According to my test results, Python finds an element in a set in 0 ns, while it takes 7048800 ns to find the same item in a list.

Are these test results accurate, or have I messed up in my test procedure?

```python
import time, csv
from itertools import chain

# RandomFilenames.csv has 1 millon rows of data
MyFile = "RandomFilenames.csv"

with open(MyFile, mode="r") as fh:
    MyList = list(chain.from_iterable(list( csv.reader(fh, delimiter='\n') )))
MySet =  set(MyList)

oneRow = '2020-01-06-11_34_42'

lastTime = time.time_ns()
if oneRow in MySet:
    print('set (ns)',time.time_ns()-lastTime)

lastTime = time.time_ns()
if oneRow in MyList:
    print('list (ns)',time.time_ns()-lastTime)
```

OUTPUT:

```
set (ns) 0
list (ns) 7048800
```

Comment: Read up on what a hash table is to find out why it's so quick. Very basic summary: You hash the object and place it in the hash table. Since two objects that are the same have the same hash, you can instantly know whether a set contains that object already so you don't have to look through every item.

Comment: No, it's correct. This is the beginning of time complexity and big O notation. Basically, the worst-case scenario for a list is going through each and every item -- but only once. N items --> O(n). But a set uses (as Loocid notes) a hash table which is the same time no matter how big --> O(1).